# Calculating ordered permutations on nonogram rows

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

So I came across [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/8je7rk/combinatorics_calculating_ordered_permutations_on/) post on reddit the other day talking about the number of all possible ways to solve a nonogram row, stating the solution is $\begin{pmatrix}n-m+1\\
k
\end{pmatrix}$ (only if it is defined of course) where $n$ is the length of the row, $k$ is the number of blocks, and $m$ is the sum of the blocks (how many cells must be colored in black).

Now reading some of the comments and explanations I'm having a hard time understanding why this is true...

---

What I'd like to know is:

1. Why is this solution correct? Can you also provide an intuitive explanation?
2. If instead of solving a completely empty row and counting how many possible solutions there are we were to already color some of the cells in white or black (as an additional restriction), how many solutions would there be now?

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: @Ekin fixed, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The intuitive explanation would be the following: Instead of coloring black, think of it as having white squares that you want to separate via gaps (these gaps can also be on the edges of the row). The distances between gaps are unimportant, except they cannot be directly next to each other. You have $n-m$ such white squares. How can you place the gaps? You pick $k$ among the $n-m+1$ possibilities for gaps (again, edges of the row included). The lengths of the black gaps are pre-defined, so you don't need to make any choices for these and you are done.

EDIT: Think of it as follows. You have $n-m$ math books and $m$ science books. Some of the science books are series, so you go to the binding store and bind them in larger chunks, so that you have $k$ larger books at the end (note that in the row, you want to place entire black blocks and not black tiles one by one, so this is exactly what happens). You don't do anything to math books.

Then you go home. Now it is time to sort the books onto your bookshelf. You don't care about their specific topic, only about their subject. How are you going to do this? You could proceed arbitrarily, or you could use some strategy. Either way, you have the same number of possibilities. So you decide to get rid of the $n-m$ math books first. You put them. Their topic doesn't matter, so there is only one possibility for this. Now to the science books. We have $k$ of them. Where can we put one book? Possibilities are: Left of math book $1$, left of math book $2$,..., left of math book $n-m$, right of math book $n-m$. If you look closely, we have $n-m+1$ possibilities here for one book. For $k$, we will choose among these possibilities (because the order of the science books doesn't matter either).

BTW, solution exists iff this number is nonnegative/well-defined.

2. is definitely more complicated.

White tiles are precolored: Then you can 'divide' the problem into two rows, however you have to make a case distinction on how many gaps are on either of the two 'new rows' (0 included, for the case that your white tile has no black block on its left/right.

Black tiles are precolored: You make case distincion on which block this tile belongs to. For each block, you make the case distinction on how the block is placed (from precolored being leftmost to rightmost). In each of these cases, you solve the original problem with two smaller rows (row minus black block we just picked) and $k-1$ remaining blocks.

Comment: why $k$ out of $n-m+1$? this point is unclear to me

Comment: Because these are exactly the places you are going to put your $k$ blocks. Again, their ordering is predefined, so it is enough to say "there is something black between these two". And $n-m+1$ is because we have $n-m$ white tiles at the end, so there are $n-m-1$ "potential gaps" between these. And then there is the left of the leftmost white tile and the right of the rightmost tile, so that makes $n-m+1$ possibilities in total. I'll edit my post with a little more explanation.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks :)

Comment: one thing unclear to me, you said the order  we place the books doesn't matter but in a nonogram it does matter (yet testing this in real life shows that indeed the formula is correct). How come? Is that a correct way of thinking about this: this is because we are choosing any k blocks which are for now empty and only after picking we place the black blocks in the order we want?

Comment: In a nonogram, a row is denoted by something like $3, 2, 4, 1$. Which means, as soon as you know how many white tiles come before any block, you have a unique coloring. White tiles are equal each other anyway. So we don't place the black blocks in any order, we place them in the order the puzzle tells us to.